# how to fetch max value from more than two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables where the column names of table B gets stored as values in table A. I need to fetch max value of columns from table B. Could you please help in acheiving this..

table A structure as follows

| id | name |

|  1  | ABC  |

|  2  | XYZ  |

table B has column names as 'ABC' and 'XYZ'. I'm stuck to fetch max of columns ABC and XYZ from table B. Any help would be of highly appreciated.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could, first, union both tables, and then calculate the maximum values. like:

SELECT max(ABC), max(XYZ) FROM(
select * from table_a
UNION ALL
select * from table_b
) table;

Comment: Thanks a lot, Forgot to mention that I'm trying to select column name from table A and it's max value from table B. Tried something like below

select A.name, max(A.name) from A,B. 

So that i can have the output as below.

A.name | max(A.name)|
ABC | max_value of field ABC|
XYZ | max_value of field XYZ |

But, in the second column of result set it shows strings instead of int.

Comment: Ok, then you could simply change the variable type, doing:  `ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY resultingcolumn INTEGER`