# How to convert comma separated string to key value array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$str = "a,b,c";
```

Can the above string be converted to an array of comma separated key value pair in php., so that the ouput is like below?

`array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c')`

Comment: Why would you want to use a key value pair when the key an value is always the same? I would suggest using explode.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: Seems a repost of your previous post https://stackoverflow.com/q/48749231/1415724

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `explode()` to achieve this.

```
$str = "a,b,c";

$array = array();

foreach( explode( ',', $str ) as $v )
{
    $array[ $v ] = $v;
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r( $array, true ).'</pre>';
```

Comment: I usually don't feed the bears myself ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner but they're so floofy!

Comment: *heh* - ah, so true. Little something for your trouble too ;-) let's see what the OP's going to do about it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `explode()` and `array_combine()`:

```
$str = "a,b,c";
$array = explode(',', $str);
$array = array_combine($array, $array);
```

Comment: +one because PHP has a function for everything! lol